# How to add additional options to docker run on Azure Service App

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-service-fabric, azure-container-registry

I am trying to run `docker run  -i --rm -d --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --name <azure-container> <azure-container-registry>/<image-name>:<tag>`

By default the container is created using `docker run -p port1:port2`

I want to remove the `-p` option and add `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` , every time my container gets created from azure container registry using App Service.

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Aarushi

Comment: Can you elaborate (in the original question) what problem is, that are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the docker command cannot be custom when you deploy your image to Azure Web App. It runs by Azure. You can add the environment variables in the App Setting, but not change the docker command.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is it not possible with Service Fabric also ? If my service fabric CI/CD pipeline is picking up image from Azure container registry and deploying to my service fabric docker container(linux) ?

Comment: @AarushiMttal I'm not working on Fabric. But it seems it's impossible.

Comment: @AarushiMttal Any updates? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a container without exposing a port, on App Services. It needs to run a server process in order to become 'healthy'. You can [use port 80 (default) or 8080](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-port-number).
Also, as Charles Xu said, you cannot add capabilities at this time.

In Service Fabric you have [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-docker-compose) port mapping options, but you should still expose a port for the [liveness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/probes-codepackage) probe.
No cap-add support here either.

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer. Please ask the "Can you elaborate (in the original question) what problem is, that are you trying to solve?" part in the comments. (mark this comment as "No longer needed")